# Task Parallelism - Am I missing something?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I'm currently implementing a file scanning utility and have implemented the following to create parallel tasks for scanning multiple folders and keeping the GIU responsive whilst the scan is under way.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => scanFiles(findType, location));
```

The line above sits in 3 overloads, one of which will iterate over multiple location values.

This came after some experiments with `BackgroundWorker` and hitting limitations around log file access etc when multiple `BackgroundWorkers` have been created.

Whilst I'm a huge fan of one line solutions I'm worried I'm missing something. The app runs fine and is working perfectly. Is it really this easy or am I missing something major in handling multiple tasks ?

Comment: Yes, this is it, thanks to [.NET Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). About the limitations at log, it's only that a file can't be accessed by multiple writers at once. If you're writing a log either do it outside of parallel tasks or put writing in asynchronous (async) method so it won't get called multiple times at once.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I already have a single function to log details. Entries in the log can be mixed as they are interrogated in Excel at a later date. Happy days :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it really this easy or am I missing something major in handling multiple tasks ?

All you are doing in the above code is to create a new thread and run your method on that thread. if that is your intnetion than you are doing it fine.

Comment: This is not accurate. Creating a `Thread` is relatively costly operation, this is why the TPL uses the thread pool, so that new thread isn't created every time.